# jScrollPane Middle-mouseclick doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

On most websites, you can press your scroll wheel and drag the mouse around in order to scroll. I use this all the time, and I'm sure others do too.

However when I use jScrollPane to replace the scroll bar, it simply doesn't work. Is there any workaround available?

Edit: Video to clarify what I mean, on the first page it works, but not on the second one.
http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cX60XpOwT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible without either 1) creating a custom method for handling middle-click and scroll or 2) in someway hiding the orginal scrollbar under something else or out of the screen. So theoretically, it's possible, but it's not included in jScrollPane at this time.